# adding a c# project to an existing c++ project in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008

I have an existing c++ project and an c# project seperately located. Now i need to add this existing c# project to the c++ project in visual studio so when i do a build on c++ project the c# project should also be built. How can i do this in visual studio 2008. And after doing this process what are list of files that will be changed (for example .sln etc etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is to add the C# project to an existing *solution*. In solution explorer, right-click on the solution and choose Add > Existing project. Select the C# project. Now you will have two projects (one C# and one C++) in your solution. When you build the solution, both projects are built.

The file that changes is the *.sln.

Answer (score 0):

[image: How you can add existing project]

Right Click on solution after that you must click on Add button as well as you must click on Existing Item and Select your cs file